# How to copy an object but not share the material using python API?

Tags: python

I use the code below to copy a cube:

```
import bpy

cube = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
cube_2 = cube.copy()
cube_2.location.y += 5
bpy.data.collections["Collection"].objects.link(cube_2)
```

[image]

The code above generates a new cube that shares the original material.
I want to generate a independent material copy while generating this new cube.
How to do it with python API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bpy

cube = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
cube_2 = cube.copy()
for slot in cube_2.material_slots:
    if slot.material:
        mat_2 = slot.material.copy()
        slot.link = 'OBJECT'
        slot.material = mat_2
cube_2.location.y += 5
bpy.data.collections["Collection"].objects.link(cube_2)
```

The `slot.link = 'OBJECT'` lets us override the material in a slot at the object level, while still sharing the same mesh.